# Pathwise solution of a stochastic integral equation, without stochastic calculus

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $f$ be a Lipschitz continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $W$ be a standard Brownian motion. I don't know any stochastic calculus (nothing about stochastic integrals, nothing about Itō's lemma), and I'm trying to prove that, for any fixed $\omega$, there exists a solution of the stochastic integral equation
$$
\xi(T)=\xi_0+\int_0^Tf(\xi(t))dt+W(T)
$$
a.s. for all $T\ge 0$.

I'm far from proving this, but it should be doable without any knowledge of stochastic calculus? Perhaps there's a useful analogue to the method of characteristics, i.e., would it be of any use to compute
$
\lim_{h\to 0}h^{-1}\mathbb{E}(\xi(T+h)-\xi(T)|\xi(T)=c)?
$
Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

(I've added the stochastic calculus and analysis tags, even though I know nothing about stochastic calculus, and I'm trying to prove this with more elementary methods.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the application
$$
F(\xi) : F(\xi)(T)=\xi_0+\int_0^Tf(\xi(t))dt+W(T)
$$

$$
\left[ F(\xi) - F(\zeta)\right] (T) = 
\int_0^T \left[f(\xi(t)) - f(\zeta(t))\right]  dt
$$
under the same assumptions as in the Cauchy Lipschitz theorem,
you can prove that (for the right space and right norm) 
$F$ is Lipschitz with constant $<1$ (the proof is exactly the same, as the stochastic terms have cancelled); hence $F$ has an only fixed point.

Comment: I don't see how the [Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem) applies in this case. The Lipschitz condition in its hypothesis applies to the function associated with the differential, not integral equation (and W is not differentiable)?

Comment: The Cauchy Lipschitz does not apply. But the proof of  this theorem is very similar to the proof of the Cauchy theorem using the fixed point theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to me there remain quite a few technical points to be settled.

Comment: yes, in particular the choice of the space.